# Error running PowerCLI from Docker image on Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, powercli

I have a Gitlab CI/CD setup that pulls the vmware/powerclicore image from Dockerhub and runs a ps1 script. This script runs correctly on a Windows host, or interactively from the Docker image, but fails if ran through the Gitlab CI/CD with the error:

```
Set-NetworkAdapter : 02/04/2020 20:28:38    Set-NetworkAdapter      Length cannot be less than zero.
 Parameter name: length
```

The gitlab-ci.yml is:

```
veeam-map-rep-networks:
  image:
    name: vmware/powerclicore
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - pwsh powershell/ps_dr_replication_remapping.ps1 -pass $vCenterPassword
```

ps_dr_replication_remapping.ps1 is:

```
 # Define passed in variables
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$pass
)
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Scope AllUsers -Confirm:$false
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -ParticipateInCeip $false -Confirm:$false
$ConfirmPreference = "None"

Connect-VIServer -Server server.example.com -User administrator@example.com -Password $pass -Force
Write-Host (Get-VM -Name "REDACTED-VM-Name")
Write-Host (Get-VM -Name "REDACTED-VM-Name" | Get-NetworkAdapter -Name "Network adapter 1")
Get-VM -Name "REDACTED-VM-Name" | Get-NetworkAdapter -Name "Network adapter 1" | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName "Target Network" 
Write-Host ($error[0].Exception | select *)
Write-Host ($error[0].Exception.InnerException | select *)
```

Output of script in Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.7.0 (58272c27)
   on REDACTED
Using Docker executor with image vmware/powerclicore ...
00:00
 Pulling docker image vmware/powerclicore ...
 Using docker image sha256:ad74fa86c83bc47805e3db4b40b7baeb847d1c1924f7bb99d9cbdcecd7a55a6a for vmware/powerclicore ...
Running on runner-REDACTED via REDACTED...
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
00:01
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in REDACTED
  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/114987846 -> refs/pipelines/114987846
    104dcbf..5978962  REDACTED
 Skipping Git submodules setup
$ TZ=":US/Eastern" date
00:07
 Tue Feb  4 20:28:31  2020
 $ pwsh powershell/ps_dr_replication_remapping.ps1 -pass $pass
 WARNING: Please consider joining the VMware Customer Experience Improvement Program, so you can help us make PowerCLI a better product. You can join using the following command:
 Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $true
 VMware's Customer Experience Improvement Program ("CEIP") provides VMware with information that enables VMware to improve its products and services, to fix problems, and to advise you on how best to deploy and use our products.  As part of the CEIP, VMware collects technical information about your organizations use of VMware products and services on a regular basis in association with your organizations VMware license key(s).  This information does not personally identify any individual.
 For more details: type "help about_ceip" to see the related help article.
 To disable this warning and set your preference use the following command and restart PowerShell: 
 Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $true or $false.
 WARNING: The cmdlet "Get-PowerCLIVersion" is deprecated. Please use the 'Get-Module' cmdlet instead.
 VMware PowerCLI 11.5.0 build 14912921
 REDACTED-VM-Name <--This confirms connection to vCenter and VM
 Network adapter 1 <--This confirms I can see the portgroup
 Set-NetworkAdapter : 02/04/2020 20:28:38   Set-NetworkAdapter      Length cannot be less than zero.
 Parameter name: length 
 At REDACTED/powershell/ps_dr_replication_remapping.ps1:32 char:87
 + ... etwork adapter 1" | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName "Target Network"
 +                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-NetworkAdapter], VimException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_BaseCmdlet_UnknownError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.VirtualDevice.SetNetworkAdapter

 @{ErrorId=Core_BaseCmdlet_UnknownError; ErrorCategory=NotSpecified; TargetObject=; RecommendedAction=Error occured while executing cmdlet: Set-NetworkAdapter. Check inner exception for more details.; SessionId=; ConnectionId=; Severity=Error; Message=02/04/2020 20:28:38 Set-NetworkAdapter      Length cannot be less than zero.
 Parameter name: length ; Data=System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal; InnerException=System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
 Parameter name: length
    at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.StringUtil.TruncateToBufferCellWidth(PSHostRawUserInterface rawUI, String toTruncate, Int32 maxWidthInBufferCells) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/utils/StringUtil.cs:line 46
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressNode.RenderFullDescription(String description, String indent, Int32 maxWidth, PSHostRawUserInterface rawUi, ArrayList strCollection, Boolean isFullPlus) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressNode.cs:line 214
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressNode.LinesRequiredInFullStyleMethod(PSHostRawUserInterface rawUi, Int32 maxWidth, Boolean isFullPlus) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressNode.cs:line 441
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressNode.LinesRequiredMethod(PSHostRawUserInterface rawUi, Int32 maxWidth) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressNode.cs:line 398
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PendingProgress.HeightTallyer.Visit(ProgressNode node, ArrayList unused, Int32 unusedToo) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/PendingProgress.cs:line 678
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PendingProgress.NodeVisitor.VisitNodes(ArrayList nodes, NodeVisitor v) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/PendingProgress.cs:line 1005
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PendingProgress.TallyHeight(PSHostRawUserInterface rawUi, Int32 maxHeight, Int32 maxWidth) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/PendingProgress.cs:line 715
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PendingProgress.Render(Int32 maxWidth, Int32 maxHeight, PSHostRawUserInterface rawUI) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/PendingProgress.cs:line 581
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressPane.Show(PendingProgress pendingProgress) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressPane.cs:line 182
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostUserInterface.HandleIncomingProgressRecord(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord record) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHostUserInterfaceProgress.cs:line 96
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostUserInterface.WriteProgress(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord record) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHostUserInterface.cs:line 1219
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.WriteProgress(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord record) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/InternalHostUserInterface.cs:line 562
    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteProgress(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord progressRecord, Boolean overrideInquire) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs:line 414
    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteProgress(ProgressRecord progressRecord, Boolean overrideInquire) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs:line 355
    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteProgress(ProgressRecord progressRecord) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs:line 325
    at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteProgress(ProgressRecord progressRecord) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/cmdlet.cs:line 563
    at VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.Util10Ps.BaseCmdlet.BaseCmdlet.ProgressCallback(Task task, Object result, Boolean writeResultToScreen)
    at VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.Util10Ps.BaseCmdlet.BaseCmdlet.EndProcessingErrorHandled()
    at VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Util10Ps.BaseCmdlet.BaseCmdlet.EndProcessingErrorHandled(); TargetSite=Void ThrowTerminatingError(System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord); StackTrace=   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs:line 2055; HelpLink=; Source=System.Management.Automation; HResult=-2146232832}
 @{Message=Length cannot be less than zero.
 Parameter name: length; ActualValue=; ParamName=length; Data=System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal; InnerException=; TargetSite=System.String Substring(Int32, Int32); StackTrace=   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.StringUtil.TruncateToBufferCellWidth(PSHostRawUserInterface rawUI, String toTruncate, Int32 maxWidthInBufferCells) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/utils/StringUtil.cs:line 46
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressNode.RenderFullDescription(String description, String indent, Int32 maxWidth, PSHostRawUserInterface rawUi, ArrayList strCollection, Boolean isFullPlus) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressNode.cs:line 214
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressNode.LinesRequiredInFullStyleMethod(PSHostRawUserInterface rawUi, Int32 maxWidth, Boolean isFullPlus) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressNode.cs:line 441
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressNode.LinesRequiredMethod(PSHostRawUserInterface rawUi, Int32 maxWidth) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressNode.cs:line 398
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PendingProgress.HeightTallyer.Visit(ProgressNode node, ArrayList unused, Int32 unusedToo) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/PendingProgress.cs:line 678
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PendingProgress.NodeVisitor.VisitNodes(ArrayList nodes, NodeVisitor v) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/PendingProgress.cs:line 1005
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PendingProgress.TallyHeight(PSHostRawUserInterface rawUi, Int32 maxHeight, Int32 maxWidth) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/PendingProgress.cs:line 715
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PendingProgress.Render(Int32 maxWidth, Int32 maxHeight, PSHostRawUserInterface rawUI) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/PendingProgress.cs:line 581
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressPane.Show(PendingProgress pendingProgress) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ProgressPane.cs:line 182
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostUserInterface.HandleIncomingProgressRecord(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord record) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHostUserInterfaceProgress.cs:line 96
    at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostUserInterface.WriteProgress(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord record) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHostUserInterface.cs:line 1219
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.WriteProgress(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord record) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/InternalHostUserInterface.cs:line 562
    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteProgress(Int64 sourceId, ProgressRecord progressRecord, Boolean overrideInquire) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs:line 414
    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteProgress(ProgressRecord progressRecord, Boolean overrideInquire) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs:line 355
    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteProgress(ProgressRecord progressRecord) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs:line 325
    at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteProgress(ProgressRecord progressRecord) in /usr/src/photon/BUILD/PowerShell-6.2.3/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/cmdlet.cs:line 563
    at VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.Util10Ps.BaseCmdlet.BaseCmdlet.ProgressCallback(Task task, Object result, Boolean writeResultToScreen)
    at VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.Util10Ps.BaseCmdlet.BaseCmdlet.EndProcessingErrorHandled()
    at VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Util10Ps.BaseCmdlet.BaseCmdlet.EndProcessingErrorHandled(); HelpLink=; Source=System.Private.CoreLib; HResult=-2146233086}
Running after script...
00:02
 $ TZ=":US/Eastern" date
 Tue Feb  4 20:28:39  2020
 Job succeeded
```

Why would Gitlab's runner cause this to fail on the same Docker image I can manually make it run as? The Gitlab output confirms I'm connecting to vCenter and can see the VM's and Portgroups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue. It looked like a bug in the vmware/powerclicore docker image.

So I used the docker image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell instead of vmware/powerclicore and ran the following commands to install powercli module to its powershell instance. All other powerCLI commands should follow after them.

Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted

Install-Module VMware.PowerCLI -Confirm:$false

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the PowerShell progress bar on Photon OS based image. In order to avoid it set

$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

on top of the script.

Answer (score 1):

We updated the powerclicore image with a fix. The progress bar is disabled by default to avoid this exception.

The images with the workaround are **vmware/powercli:latest**and **vmware/powercli:12.2.1**

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue using the powerclicore container.  I found I was able to workaround the issue by passing the object directly into the set command rather than through the pipeline.

Try this instead:

`$netadapter = Get-VM -Name "REDACTED-VM-Name" | Get-NetworkAdapter -Name "Network adapter 1"
Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkAdapater $netadapter -NetworkName "Target Network"`